# Java generic return type not used in parameters

Tags: java, generics

In a java library I came across a method which uses a generic return type that is not used in any way in the parameters:

```
<T extends ResponseCallBack> T sendData(@Nonnull final OrderIf checkoutOrder, @Nullable final List<NameValueIf> ccParmList) throws Exception;
```

(`ResponseCallBack` is an interface here)

What is the difference with this signature:

```
ResponseCallBack sendData(@Nonnull final OrderIf checkoutOrder, @Nullable final List<NameValueIf> ccParmList)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that you can use this special version for method chaining.

Check this sample program:

```
public class MyFoo {
    public <T extends MyFoo> T foo(){
        System.out.println("foo");
        return (T) this;
    }

    static class MyBar extends MyFoo{
        public <T extends MyBar> T bar(){
            System.out.println("bar");
            return (T) this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyFoo foo = new MyFoo().foo();
        final MyBar bar1 = new MyBar().foo();
        final MyBar bar2 = new MyBar().bar();
    }

}
```

The assignment of the bar1 variable is only possible because of the `<T extends MyFoo>`, without it, there would have to be a cast:

```
final MyBar bar1 = (MyBar) new MyBar().foo();
```

Unfortunately, at least with Java 7, compiler inference ends here, so you can't do

```
new MyBar().foo().bar();
```

Comment: And when this kind of chaining became useful?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno whether it's a nice pattern or not is up for discussion, but method chaining is certainly less error-prone, since you don't have to store any intermediate variables, nor have to make sure whether a method returns the original or a new instance.

Comment: Yeah i know it's great, i was just worrying when using this "kind" with generics was useful. (Since it gives me unchecked cast in intellij idea). Anyway you are right, he don't want to know when it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is with the first parameter the caller can constrain the type that is returned to some extent, while for the second you only know that you'll get a `ResponseCallBack` and will have to perform a cast if you want a subtype.

For example, with the first you can do:

```
Subtype temp = caller.<subtype> sendData(...); // Can also skip explicitly passing the type parameter too
```

instead of

```
Subtype temp = (Subtype) caller.sendData(...);
```

So I suppose it's a way of ensuring type safety when calling, as well as allowing the caller to eliminate casts from his/her code.